# What are these 2 black pvc pipes with wire

Tags: wiring, pvc, backyard

I have 2 black PVC pipes in my side yard. One is capped and the other is uncapped with a wire looped around the capped tube. I tested the wire with my voltage tester and multimeter and got nothing to register between ground and black/white/red.

Hoping to get a better idea of what it might be without digging it up.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks to be irrigation related. I’d imagine a valve there, actuated by the wire that traces back to a controller/timer. If you find a bundle of similar wires, you can figure out which is which with the resistance setting on the multimeter.

If it isn’t leaking, you can ignore it.